# Email to Salesforce not working for One email ID

Tags: email, email2salesforce

The Salesforce feature Email-Salesforce lets users send a mail to a unique link, which is then shown in Salesforce 'My Unresolved Items'.

A user uses two different email Id's and both are added in the 'My Acceptable Email Addresses'. Yet emails sent from one of his email Id are not shown in Salesforce.

-We have checked with other users email Ids, it works fine with all. Issue lies with only 1 of his email Id.

How can we troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

check if by mistake you have added the Domain of that mail id in 'Excluded Domains'